# Best way for live updates?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a site at www.casualdispatch.com that basically updates people as jobs are being dispatched from a physical dispatch window where tickets are being handed out. Currently, users must refresh the page manually but I would like the update to function without a page reload. How can I accomplish this? Currently, I am using php and each update is made by posting a form and adding mysql records of each update.

These jobs are also dispatched very quickly, one after another. Its also very hard to input them one by one. I'd like to make a form that consists of a table with everyone's dispatch number and when you touch one it marks it off leaving it highlighted and then updates the main page. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, it's probably possible.

Comment: You should ask specific questions. Focus on one aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way for live updates is to fetch them from your php script with an Ajax request, and then update it client side with javascript..

Comment: Thank you for the straight forward answer.